# Change Button value via JS

Tags: javascript, button

```
<button class="btn btn-big btn-primary" id="geolocateMe" type="submit">Goooo!</button>
```

Please how in JS I can change the Goooo! value into a button ?

I've tried:

```
document.getElementById('geolocateMe').value = "Test";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to change the text of the button?

```
document.getElementById('geolocateMe').innerText = "Test";
```

Comment: Glad it worked out :) The reason your jsfiddle didn't work had to do with the order it loads the different panels: http://jsfiddle.net/hZQ2H/4/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
document.getElementById('geolocateMe').innerHTML = "Test";
```